# Why do I get emty string from Xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

Please help me to understand why my code returns empty string instead of text of span. I'm newbie in it, I get Response 200, did the same steps as with another site (it works there) but in this case not without any errors at the end.
This is html code I'm parsing, I need to get string "Cessna Citation CJ3"

```
<div class="acTitle" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"> 
  <i class="fa fa-plane"></i> <span ng-bind="flight.ac.title" class="ng- binding">Cessna Citation CJ3</span>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'https://flyeasy.co/opapi/-fe3-dt1--ht2--ht3--ht4-ctp:magellanjets_list:-/' \
        '578526bdf6c494c11477ab06/'

headers = {
    'user-agent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'
}

def parse_data(url, headers):
    titles = []
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(response)
    except:
        return
    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(response.text)
    for item in tree.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "acTitle")]'):
        title = item.xpath(".//span/text()")
        print(title)
        titles.append(title)
        print(titles)
        print(len(titles))


parse_data(url, headers)
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you quoting the HTML you saw in your browser, or the actual content in `response.text`? Those aren't always the same -- a browser will often perform DOM fixups during parsing.

Comment: @Charles Duffy not silly, I took HTML from Chrome, not from response. I didn't now there can be differece, can you, please, explain?

Comment: For what it's worth, using the sample data at the top of your question, your code seems to work fine (although note that the `xpath` method always returns a list, never a string, so when setting `title` you might want to take that into account).

Comment: @larsks Unfortunatly not working fine, it returns emty lists

Comment: @Копатыч, as I said, DOM fixups. HTML has multiple ways to write things, so sometimes a browser will normalize content as it loads it so the rendering engine can assume a specific interpretation instead of needing to support multiple possibilities. You should be able to tell if that's the case here by looking at the actual response text and seeing if relevant content differs.

Comment: @Копатыч, ...it's also worth inspecting `response.text` to see if there's something going on like real content being loaded in by javascript and not being there in the initial  plain-HTML response at all.

Comment: @Копатыч, ...in general, if you want a _supported_, supportable way to scrape a site's data, you should try to get an API that's properly supported by the people who run it. If they don't want you scraping, they have an indefinite number of ways to break your scraper (and trying to figure out which one they're using in any given day is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, given the question's near-indefinite scope and the potential for a "right" answer to suddenly become a wrong one as soon as the server side is updated).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your answers and time! I caught allready from the answer below that not every site is similar to one I've parsed allready and I need to learn much more in coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of that site is heavily dynamic. It is not available in the page source. When you print `response.text` or check manually using (ctrl + u), you won't see the desired content.

However, there is an api avilable which contains all the information that you see in that page including the lazy-loaded ones. Given that the following script should get you all the titles from that page.

When you execute the script, it may take substantial amount of time to return the results, so wait until you see the output in the console.

```
import requests

api_link = "https://flyeasy.co/api/search"
start_link = 'https://flyeasy.co/opapi/-fe3-dt1--ht2--ht3--ht4-ctp:magellanjets_list:-/578526bdf6c494c11477ab06/'

opid = start_link.split("/")[-2]

params = {"opIds":[f"{opid}"],"trip":"offers","source":"eq","promoteOpIds":"all"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Referer'] = start_link
    res = s.post(api_link,json=params)
    for item in res.json()['flights']['departing']:
        print(item['ac']['title'])
```

Comment: It works, but now I understand that "my powers are weak" and I need to learn much more to parse such sites, cause I don't understand how to get params from your code. Thank you very much for your time and answer!

Comment: By the way, is there anything to understand that site is so "heavy" to parse? Maybe somethg in url or in site code in browser?

Comment: As the required content of that site are loaded later, they are not in the page source, so there is hardly any option other than the way I've already shown if you stick with requests module. However, you can still get the content using the selectors you have tried above, if you go for selenium. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you not me! I have quet fast internet so its not clear to get the time of page loading is short or not. I thought that "/opapi/" or something like this is an option to check that url is not "simple"

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/gMCq1Ayk) is something you can do to get the titles using selenium.

Comment: Wow! Thank you again, I've tryed selenium once but stacked somewhere and now it seems i need to have a look on it again